# Is there a way to use todonotes in standalone

Tags: standalone, todonotes

Considering the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,crop=false,a4paper,class=book]{standalone}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\todo{Bug}
\end{document}
```

During the compilation process the compiler prints:

> You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. \enddocument ...
>   \endgroup \deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
>                                                      l.8 \end{document}

Is there a way to make the `todonotes` save to use in the `standalone` class?

I would like to have single compilable chapters that I can compile together without changing the preamble everytime. Yet I don't want to loose my handy `todonotes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that package `todonotes` needs some definition made in class `article`, but theese definitions are not available in class `standalone`.

An workaround can be the following MWE, that just loads class `article`, but uses environment `standalone` inside.  Please see that this is documentated in example 3, page 29 in the documentation of package `standalone` (use `texdoc standalone` on your terminal/console).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{standalone}{\begin{preview}}{\end{preview}}
%\input{standalone.cfg}
% which by defaults loads:
% \PassOptionsToPackage{active,tightpage}{preview}
\usepackage{preview}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{standalone}
\section{test}
text\todo{Bug} text
\end{standalone}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe above]

Comment: Assuming you meant the `\input` line to be uncommented, as in the `standalone` documentation, this doesn't work for me.  Compiling gives an `Undefined control sequence` error on line 12 of `standalone.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

It works without further modification if you use the `marginnote` package:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,crop=false,a4paper,class=book]{standalone}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\let\marginpar\marginnote

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\todo{Bug}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]